# Which Deck of Many Things cards are depicted in this art?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, content-identification, art

I found this illustration of the Deck of many Things. I don't know where this is from, but it appears to be ©2011 by Wizards of the Coast (in the bottom right of the image).

Anyway, I can't identify all the cards. Some, like the Gem or the Void, are obvious. Others, not so much. Can you identify all the cards here? The list of cards can be found [here](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/wondrous-items/#Deck_of_Many_Things).

[image]

Comment: FYI: That image has (c)2011 Wizards of the Coast in the bottom right, so it's official, and some of this art appears to be in the official D&D 5e manuals via the [Extra Life/DMG Previews](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/extra-lifedmg-previews)

Comment: This deck in particular is from the 4th Edition adventure *Madness at Gardmore Abbey.* It featured prominently in the adventure, and the module included a physical copy of the deck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found this image online which lists all of the cards shown, as well as the two missing ones.

The gallery where I found this image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8NYE.jpg)

[image: Deck of Many Things]

Comment: Well, that settles that.

Answer (score 7):

Starting on the left, row by row:

### Row 1

- Knight
- Moon
- Fates
- Donjon
- Balance
- Jester

### Row 2

- Gems
- Void
- Fool
- Vizier

### Row 3

- Idiot
- Flames
- Key
- Sun

### Row 4

- Euryale
- Rogue
- Skull
- Star
- Throne
- Comet

This leaves Talons and Ruin as the two unrepresented cards in the illustration.